# Need to start up all gemfire members with persisted data first and at the same time

Tags: gemfire

When i invoked GFSH shutdown command on my Gemfire cluster in my development environment before, I still need to wait for the rest of Gemfire Cache Server members to start up again. Why?

I thought when i invoked the GFSH shutdown command will all members running, all online data stores will be synchronized before shutting, so all hold the most recent data copy. Thus, all cache server member will have the most recent record.

**Software Configuration**

1. 4 Cache Server
2. 2 Locator
3. Gemfire 9.8.4
4. Persistence Replicated Regions

For example, if i invoked the GFSH shutdown command on the Gemfire Cluster and then perform shutdowns on all the machine. Then, i start 2 Locator and 3 Cache Servers. Will it wait for the remaining Cache Server?

Addition

**In the cache server log** :

```
[info ...19:27:02.327...... <main> tid=0x1] Created oplog#9 drf for disk store pdxMetaDataStore
[info ...19:27:02.327...... <main> tid=0x1] Created oplog#9 crf for disk store pdxMetaDataStore
[info ...19:27:02.327...... <main> tid=0x1] Deleted oplog#8 crf for disk store pdxMetaDataStore
[info ...19:27:02.327...... <main> tid=0x1] Deleted oplog#8 drf for disk store pdxMetaDataStore
[info ...19:27:02.329...... <main> tid=0x1] recovery region initialization took 17 ms
[info ...19:27:02.355...... <main> tid=0x1] Initializing region PdxTypes
[info ...19:31:31.509...... <unicast-receiver,gf-1> receive new view: View[148.88.88.100....
.....
[info ...19:31:31.514...... Admitting member...
[info ...19:31:31.514...... Region PdxTypes requesting initial image from 148.88.88.100...
[info ...19:31:31.514...... PdxTypes is done getting image from 148.88.88.100.
```

The region PdxTypes initialized finished only when another cache server is started.

**server-cache.xml**

```
<disk-store name="pdxMetaDataStore" compaction-threshold="40" auto-compact="false" allow-force-compaction="true" max-oplog-size="75" queue-size="10000" time-interval="15" write-buffer-size="65535">
<disk-dirs>
  <disk-dir dir-size="3000">/gemfire/store</disk-dir>
</disk-dirs>
</disk-store>
<pdx read-serialized="true" disk-store-name="pdxMetaDataStore" persistent="true/>
```

**GFSH**

```
Disk Store ID                        |  Host          | Directory
--------------------------------------------------------------------
66asdf-asdf-asdf-asdf-asdfafadfasfC  | 148.88.88.100  | /gemfire/store
```

**snippet thread dump**

```
"Asynchronous disk writer for region pdxMetaDataStore" #55 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0007ffcess nid=0x225d in Object.wait() [0x001....]
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.TimeUnti.timedWait(TimeUnit.java:348)
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.DiskStoreImpl$FlusherThread.waitUntilFlushIsReady(DiskStoreImpl.java:1647)
     - Locked <0x00000123123> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.DiskStoreImpl$FlusherThread.doAsyncFlush(DiskStoreImpl.java:1706)
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.DiskStoreImpl$FlusherThread.run(DiskStoreImpl.java:1696)

"main" #1 prio=5........ in Object.wait() [0x......] 
  "Java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.persistence.MembershipChangeListener.waitForChange(MembershipChangeListener.java:62)
  - Locked (0x....) (a org.apache.geode.internal.cache.persistence.MembershipChangeListener)
   at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.persistence.PersistenceInitialImageAdvisor.waitForMembershipChangeForMissingDiskStores(PersistenceInitialImageAdvisor.java:218)
   at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.persistence.PersistenceInitialImageAdvisor.getAdvice(PersistenceInitialImageAdvisor.java:118)
   at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.persistence.PeristenceAdvisorImpl.getInitialImageAdvice(PeristenceAdvisorImpl.java:835)
   at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.persistence.CreatePersistentRegionProcessor.getInitialImageAdvice(CreatePersistentRegionProcessor.java:52)
   at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.DistributedRegion.getInitialImageAndRecovery(DisritubedRegion.java:1196)
   at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.DistributedRegion.initialize(DistributedRegion.java:1076)
 ......
```

Comment: Hello Jack, for a replicated region with persistence, the last member to exit always has the most recent data; so if you stopped your servers using `gfsh shutdown` then the members should come up fine. Are you seeing an exception or something weird within the logs?, can you post that so I can have a look?.

Comment: Hello Juan Ramos, do you mean if i stopped the servers using gfsh shutdown, i don't need to wait for the rest of server members?

Comment: Hello Jack, yes, if you have `REPLICATE_PERSISTENT` regions and you shutdown your cluster using the `gfsh shutdown` command, then all members should come up just fine. You can have a look at [Start Up and Shut Down with Disk Stores](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/910/geode/managing/disk_storage/starting_system_with_disk_stores.html) for more details. It's always a recommended practice, though, to start your locators first, and then the servers in parallel.

Comment: Even though i shutdown the cluster using the gfsh shutdown command, i still need to wait for other server to initialize the region. I wrote more detail on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've just seen the updated description and log extract, these messages are common within a GemFire cluster whenever members leave or join the distributed system (internal synchronisation mechanism), they ***don't imply*** that the server is waiting for other servers to come up and finish initialisation, in such cases you would see something like the following:

```
Region /MyRegion has potentially stale data.
It is waiting for another member to recover the latest data.
My persistent id:

  DiskStore ID: 6893751ee74d4fbd-b4780d844e6d5ce7
  Name: server1
  Location: /192.0.2.0:/home/dsmith/server1/.

Members with potentially new data:
[
  DiskStore ID: 160d415538c44ab0-9f7d97bae0a2f8de
  Name: server2
  Location: /192.0.2.0:/home/dsmith/server2/.
]
Use the "gfsh show missing-disk-stores" command to see all disk stores
that are being waited on by other members.
```

You can have a look at [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Get+Initial+Image+Sequence) post for further information about the Get Initial Image Sequence sequence.

Cheers.

Comment: When i execute the gfsh show missing-disk-stores during waiting the region to be Initialized, i found out there is a missing disk store which is pointed to my other cache server. Why it did not point to its own disk store since i executed gfsh shutdown command?

Comment: Also i did not found any "Region /MyRegion has potentially stale data" in the cache server log file. It hanged on the "Initializing region PdxTypes"

Comment: What do you mean by "hanged"?, have you seen any threads stuck after looking at the thread dumps for the member?. The `PdxTypes` region is internally created a `PERSISTENT_REPLICATE` also, so you shouldn't have any issues while starting up your member is you used the `gfsh shutdown` command.

Comment: I found out there was no new entries after line "19:27:02.355...... <main> tid=0x1] Initializing region PdxType". As a result, I executed "gfsh show missing-disk-stores" command, I found out there was a missing disk store which was belonged to cache server 148.88.88.100. Then, i tried to start up the cache server 148.88.88.100 [around 19:31:31], new entries started to display in the log file.

Comment: I included snippet of thread dump which was related to pdxMetaDataStore. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I can reproduce the behaviour locally with just two servers and one locator... let me ask some questions around to see if this is the expected behaviour or not. If it's not, I'll open a Geode JIRA ticket and post the id here.

Comment: Hey Jack, I've just created [GEODE-8248](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-8248), we should either fix the synchronisation or update the documentation accordingly. You can add yourself as a watcher to receive updates on the progress. In the meantime, and as a workaround, you should start all your server members with `PERSISTENT` regions in parallel.

Comment: Thank you so much..Hopefully there is a fix to solve the synchronization issue. And, the fix is propagate to Gemfire 9.8.X version.